# recover data on external drive

Tags: data-recovery, clone

I lost all my data on an external hard driven and need help getting it back.

I first installed ubuntu 12.04 64bit in dual boot along side windows 7 64,then I updated and installed all the programs that I wanted. I then wanted to create a backup,so I went in the terminal(on live boot cd) and I cloned my 250 gig hard drive partition onto my much larger 1tb external hard drive. Well the dd did a good job and created a 250 gig partition on my drive, but now all my data is gone. when I look at the hard drive in windows, it says there are 3 partitions, one smaller partition, one cloned drive partition, and about 700gigs of unallocated space. I looked on the Internet for solutions, and I followed some instructions to use testdisk to locate missing files.

On test disk, I selected Create new log file, then I selected my 1tb hard drive, then I selected intel and went quick search. No results displayed. I then did deep search and let that run from 0% to 100%. I was able to see only the files of the partitioned portion. There was a few non ntfs folders displayed as linux, but I could not see any files in them it only said something about corruption and cannot display or something like that.

Long story short,I scanned my driver two times which took about 6 hours. Is there a way I can still get my information back?

Answer (score 2):

first of all you should install the photorec tool. tpye in terminal.
         sudo apt-get install photorec
after installing that enter the terminal as follows
         sudo photorec
it will definitely recover all the data from your disk